# Show lines found with Rosetta Code Hough Transform in original image

Tags: java, algorithm, math, image-processing

I have been using the [Rosetta Code Java implementation](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hough_transform#Java) of Hough Transform, and it also nicely generates the visualization of the accumulator.

Given an input image like this:

[image]

The accumulator looks like this:

[image: Accumulator Space]

Given that I cpompile and invoke the class like this:

```
$ javac HoughTransform.java && java HoughTransform pentagram.png out.png 640 480 100
```

Which makes sense. Now I would like to overlay the original images with the lines I found, but this gives me serious trouble.

I could only find an example which does what I want written in C++:

> ```
> ...
> int x1, y1, x2, y2;
> x1 = y1 = x2 = y2 = 0;
>
> if(t >= 45 && t <= 135)
> {
>   //y = (r - x cos(t)) / sin(t)
>   x1 = 0;
>   y1 = ((double)(r-(_accu_h/2)) - ((x1 - (_img_w/2) ) * cos(t * DEG2RAD))) / sin(t * DEG2RAD) + (_img_h / 2);
>   x2 = _img_w - 0;
>   y2 = ((double)(r-(_accu_h/2)) - ((x2 - (_img_w/2) ) * cos(t * DEG2RAD))) / sin(t * DEG2RAD) + (_img_h / 2);
> }
> else
> {
>   //x = (r - y sin(t)) / cos(t);
>   y1 = 0;
>   x1 = ((double)(r-(_accu_h/2)) - ((y1 - (_img_h/2) ) * sin(t * DEG2RAD))) / cos(t * DEG2RAD) + (_img_w / 2);
>   y2 = _img_h - 0;
>   x2 = ((double)(r-(_accu_h/2)) - ((y2 - (_img_h/2) ) * sin(t * DEG2RAD))) / cos(t * DEG2RAD) + (_img_w / 2);
> }
> ...
> ```
>
> *From https://github.com/brunokeymolen/hough/blob/master/hough.cpp#L125*

I tried adapting the code at least to see if I can get the general idea, but the implementation for the C++ version and the Rosetta code version seem kind of different.

I implemented:

```
public static void getLines(String filename, int thetaAxisSize, ArrayData arrayData)  throws IOException
{
  BufferedImage inputImage = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));

  double[] sinTable = new double[thetaAxisSize];
  double[] cosTable = new double[thetaAxisSize];
  for (int theta = thetaAxisSize - 1; theta >= 0; theta--)
  {
    double thetaRadians = theta * Math.PI / thetaAxisSize;
    sinTable[theta] = Math.sin(thetaRadians);
    cosTable[theta] = Math.cos(thetaRadians);
  }


  java.awt.Color color = new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0);

  int max = arrayData.getMax();
  System.out.println("Max value: " + max);

  for (int r = 0; r < arrayData.height; r++)
  {
    for (int theta = 0; theta < arrayData.width; theta++)
    {
      int val = arrayData.get(theta, r);

      if (val < max - 1) {
        continue;
      }

      System.out.println("Found val: " + val + ", r: " + r + ", theta: " + theta);

      int x = (int)(r * cosTable[theta]);
      int y = (int)(r * sinTable[theta]);

      System.out.println("Found val: " + val + ", r: " + r + ", theta: " + theta + ", x/y: " + x + "/" + y);
    }
  }

  ImageIO.write(inputImage, "PNG", new File("/tmp/hough-overlay.png"));
}
```

But then got stuck, as the result is already non-sensical to me:

```
Max value: 217 (this one still makes sense)
Found val: 216, r: 275, theta: 342
Found val: 216, r: 275, theta: 342, x/y: -29/273
Found val: 216, r: 276, theta: 340
Found val: 216, r: 276, theta: 340, x/y: -27/274
Found val: 217, r: 277, theta: 337
Found val: 217, r: 277, theta: 337, x/y: -23/276
Found val: 217, r: 277, theta: 339
Found val: 217, r: 277, theta: 339, x/y: -25/275
Found val: 217, r: 278, theta: 336
Found val: 217, r: 278, theta: 336, x/y: -21/277
Found val: 216, r: 279, theta: 334
Found val: 216, r: 279, theta: 334, x/y: -19/278
```

My mathematics is not good enough to find out how I can transform `r` and `theta` back to the image space, given a line is found. I read many whitepapers and articles on Hough Transform, I still don't understand. The few implementations that I found, like the C++ version, all seem to do it a little bit different from the Java version that I have.

So I wonder, has anyone used the Rosetta Code Java implementation for Hough Transform and managed to transform the lines back from the polar space into the original image?

Comment: Have you got five clusters of close r/theta pairs around max values for this pentagon?

Comment: @MBo Hm what do you mean? According to the hough space image, the lines are detected correctly.

Comment: Yes, and your problem is to get positions of these bright places, isn't it?

Comment: @MBo yes exactly, filtering the hough space is pretty obvious to me. If a point in hough space is above the threshold, it can be considered part of a line. I then have the angle theta and r but I don't really get how to transform that back to two x/y coordinates that represent the matched line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have parameters rho, theta of "normal" line equation and want to get two points defining the same line

```
 x *  Cos(Theta) + y * sin(Theta) - Rho = 0
```

Special cases: check whether Rho = 0 or Theta is 90*K (horizontal or vertical).

1. `Rho = 0` - line through coordinate origin. So the first point is `(0,0)`. If Theta = 0, take `(0, 1)` as second point, otherwise take `(1, Cotangent(Theta))`
2. If Theta = 0 or 180 (vertical) - just make vertical line `X=Rho` (for example, points `(Rho, 0) and (Rho,1)`)
3. If Theta = 90/270 (horizontal) - just make horizontal line `Y=Rho` (for example, points `(0, Rho) and (1, Rho)`)

Otherwise - let's choose intersections with coordinate axes as base line points. Substitute x=0 and y=0 in equation and get coordinates:

```
 0 *  Cos(Theta) + y * sin(Theta) - Rho = 0
 y = Rho / Sin(Theta)

 x *  Cos(Theta) + 0 * sin(Theta) - Rho = 0      
 x = Rho / Cos(Theta)
```

So points are `(0, Rho / Sin(Theta))` and `(Rho / Cos(Theta), 0)`

Quick check for `Theta = 45, Rho = 0.7071`:
`(0, 1)` and `(1, 0)` - OK

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will need to check that in detail. What does "Substitute x=0 and y=0 in equation and get coordinates" mean? and "Theta is 90*K" what is `K`? Thanks!

Comment: I showed substitution. K is integer: 90*K=0, 90, 180, 270

Comment: Could you give me an example of the calculation needed in context of this: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/39/Hough_transform_diagram.png ? So basically each cell in the accumulator represents a line. I would now need to find one x/y point on that line. In that image, the green line at 30 deg - I could say the intersection of that green line is x/y and use that then for reversing to normal form?

Comment: I wonder - have you read my post with ready-to-use formulas `So points are...`?  Rho is Dist, Theta is Angle (don't forget to convert degrees into radians)

Comment: I understand now, thank you! I didn't grok the part that I have to use the intersection with the axis as one of the base points, thanks. Now it makes sense to me. I still need to work out how to a) handle the special cases you mentioned and b) implement it in the Java lib, but now I understand the theory.

Comment: I gave example for special cases too. `if (angle=0) {return(Rho, 0),(Rho,1)}`

Comment: I have one more question, in the example https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/39/Hough_transform_diagram.png - there is a blue line at 150 deg. So the line continues to the top right "outside" of my image, basically into infinity. How can I find the endpoint for a line like that?

Comment: It think difficulties might arise with line through origin (like blue line on the left picture), made addition.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is tangent lines on circles. If you read all the articles about Hough you will know that it calculates the lines that potentially pass through a point and votes for them on polar space ( the most votes win the line):

To work out the transformation you reverse the transformation:

```
public static void data(ArrayData outputData, int theta, int r, int maxR) {  
    int w=outputData.width, h=outputData.height;
    int halfRAxisSize = r >>> 1;  
    int max=0, maxr=0, maxth=0, maxi=0, maxj=0; 
    for (int i=0; i<outputData.width; i++)
      for (int j=0; j<outputData.height; j++)
        if (outputData.dataArray[i+j*outputData.width]>max) {
          max=outputData.dataArray[i+j*outputData.width]; maxi=i; maxj=j;
        }       
    double R=(maxj-halfRAxisSize)*maxR/halfRAxisSize;
    double th=1.0*maxi/theta, tha=(1.0*maxi/theta)*180;   
    System.out.println("max "+R+" "+th+" "+tha+" "+max+" w h "+w+" "+h);
    }
```

and you call it like this

```
public static void m() {
  ArrayData inputData = getArrayDataFromImage("../h-5.png");
  ArrayData outputData = houghTransform(inputData, 640, 480, 100);

  int width = inputData.width;
  int height = inputData.height;
  int maxRadius = (int)Math.ceil(Math.hypot(width, height));    
  data(outputData, 640, 480, maxRadius);    
}
```

I have done several experiments with single lines and it seems to work - excluding the round off errors (I work with integers) it seems to abide (the last one you dont see because it goes into negative rho):

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

So you have to figure out the perpendicular line (black) from the red line.

In multi-line cases you have to remove areas around a max because a lot of values are similar around the max, before going to the next max area.

--

To draw the lines I used the following code. Since the y direction is flipped during the computation of Hough the center of coordinates is at 0, h-1 in the image, i.e. the nornal coordinate system.

```
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2f));
//  g2.drawLine(100, 100, 200, 150);
//  g2.drawLine(100, 100, 200, 200);
//  g2.drawLine(100, 200, 200, 50);
    g2.drawLine(100, 100, 100, 200);
//  g2.drawLine(100, 100, 200, 100);


    g2.setColor(Color.red);
//    int r=170, th=63, rr=r; // 170 63, 168 45, -63 147, 98 0, 138 90
//    int r=168, th=45, rr=r;
//    int r=-63, th=147, rr=(int)Math.abs(r);
    int r=98, th=0, rr=(int)Math.abs(r);
//    int r=138, th=90, rr=(int)Math.abs(r);
    g2.drawOval(-rr, h-1-rr, 2*rr, 2*rr);
    g2.drawLine(0, h-1, (int)(rr*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(th))), h-1-(int)(rr*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(th))));
```